# Fit data over interval of a function

Tags: fitting

I want to fit a function but just over an specific interval, so I can extract the best fit value. My whole data set does not resemble any function at all, but just a section of it.

Here is how my data looks like:

```
{{-797699.9999999999, -2.9872351682079851993`19.475269413509647*^-8}, \

   {-740721.4285714286, 
  8.4632398949230742296`19.92753665135178*^-8}, 
   {-683742.8571428572, 3.467564081390099341`18.54002449568244*^-7}, 
   {-626764.2857142857, 
  6.030535494107199418`18.780355877946143*^-7}, 
   {-569785.7142857143, 9.4577503141223573303`19.975787844398138*^-7}, 
   {-512807.1428571428, 1.7394086164545772591`19.240401617095092*^-6}, 
   {-455828.5714285714, 2.2605083476805153548`19.354206115150404*^-6}, 
   {-398849.99999999994, 
  2.5325995630360947368`19.403566527606745*^-6}, 
   {-341871.4285714286, 
  3.486500620893185147`18.542389746882243*^-6}, 
   {-284892.8571428571, 4.7991413394385014485`19.681163540520945*^-6}, 
   {-227914.28571428565, 
  7.279209211116279807`18.86208420157915*^-6}, 
   {-170935.7142857143, 0.00001309936979383075591`18.117250402400394}, 
   {-113957.14285714287, 
  0.00006760310871981594729`18.829966667373874}, 
   {-56978.571428571384, 0.0066331446869846597398`19.821719470549354}, 
   {0., -0.00019812123796179321439`19.29693103301068}, 
   {56978.5714285715, -0.005844380135961151177`18.766738455992783}, 
   {113957.14285714287, \
-0.000060467652876468341415`19.781523111278652}, 
   {170935.7142857143, \
-0.0000143513976273976455915`20.156894197398216}, 
   {227914.28571428574, -9.419582304920213271`18.974031645182453*^-6}, 
   {284892.8571428573, -6.0892818755197918122`19.784566078201248*^-6}, 
   {341871.42857142864, -4.2567434439560184243`19.62907747582153*^-6}, 
   {398850., -2.8131484875965066331`19.449192656318004*^-6}, 
   {455828.5714285714, -2.6321600872122690062`19.42031229940948*^-6}, \

   {512807.1428571428, -2.0076099565645388063`19.302679340860546*^-6}, 
   {569785.7142857142, -1.4340496133020019803`19.15656417672269*^-6}, \

   {626764.2857142858, -1.0083905656104379052`19.003628773812725*^-6}, 
   {683742.8571428572, -6.4285640196797904765`19.808113973238903*^-7}, 
   {740721.4285714286, -3.3563509469525574742`19.52586736525448*^-7}, \

   {797699.9999999999, -1.2756831161653206887`19.105742807620153*^-7}}
```

[image]

However, I'm just interested in fitting on side of the data set to the function:

```
Manipulate[
 Plot[(-(( S 0.65)/(2 Hx - Hk))) /. {Hk -> 58000}, {Hx, -1.2/
    Subscript[\[Mu], 0], 1.2/Subscript[\[Mu], 0]}, 
  Epilog -> Point[dat[[15 ;;]]]], {S, 0.1, 8}]
```

[image]

I adjusted the value "by-hands" to ~6, but when I'm using the `FindFit` function I get a any higher value for the coefficient!

```
FindFit[dat[[14 ;;]], (-(( S 0.65)/(2 Hx - 58000))), {S}, Hx]
```

[image]

I struggled with this kind of issues always: having a subset of data and trying to fit to 'intervals' of an specific function.

How can I do that?

Comment: Please post code, not images, and include your dataset, it is small.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. I dedited the question.

Answer (score 1):

This is just an extended comment:  You probably want `dat[18;;]]` rather than `dat[14;;]]` or `dat[[15;;]]` as seen below:

```
ListPlot[{dat, dat[[14 ;;]]}, PlotRange -> All, PlotStyle -> {Blue, {Red, PointSize[0.02]}}]
```

[image]

But even then the model is not a good fit to the data.

Comment: I know the data is not the adequate, I oversimplified my general problem for asking for help

Comment: I'd like to know how to fit data by intervales

Comment: I don't think there's anything more to it than choosing the data that is in the interval of interest.  Maybe there's more to the story that you're not telling.  You did leave off the definition of $\mu_0$.  I do understand the difficulty of giving just the right amount of information to describe the issue and not giving too much potentially irrelevant information.

Comment: I now wonder if what you're after is replacing something like `dat[[14;;]` with `Select[dat, #[[1]] > 100000 &]`.